# How to get a non-floating grid of pictures with captions for some of the pictures

Tags: tables, spacing, floats, captions

I'm really struggling with this one... 
I want to create a book from a blog with around 5.000 pics and text. I wrote a little converter, to create a valid tex-File from the xml-file I got from the blog.

Since the number of pics is that big, I need to scale them down and want to put up to 4 pics in a row. Sometimes there are more than 30 pics before there is the next text-element. For that case there should be some kind of grid for the pics that can extend to several pages. The images should be non floating because there isn't any real reference in the text... you just get the meaning because of there position. Some of the pics have a caption that should be displayed aswell.

So I tried to generate a table of images but noticed that even with the "longtable" package it doesn't seem to be possible to extend a table on more than one page. That is why I tried to create a table for each row of pics. I'm making progress but I can't get captions to work in the non-floating tabular-environment.

I tried several options already but none of them seem to meet all my requirements.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}[c]{cccc}
\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{D:/Blogfotos3/wpid-p8220063.jpg}\captionof{figure}{Testing}&
\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{D:/Blogfotos3/wpid-p8220070.jpg}&
\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{D:/Blogfotos3/wpid-p8220092.jpg}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Spacing are looking quite good with this solution but captions are not working.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.24\textwidth}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{D:/Blogfotos3/wpid-img_7064.jpg}\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.24\textwidth}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{D:/Blogfotos3/wpid-dsc5085-edit.jpg}\caption{\centering Scorpionfish}\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.24\textwidth}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{D:/Blogfotos3/wpid-dsc5195-edit.jpg}\caption{\centering Schnegge}\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.24\textwidth}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{D:/Blogfotos3/wpid-dsc5236.jpg}\caption{\centering Noch ne Schnegge}\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.24\textwidth}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{D:/Blogfotos3/wpid-dsc5178.jpg}\caption{\centering Orang-utan-Crab}\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.24\textwidth}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{D:/Blogfotos3/wpid-dsc5022.jpg}\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.24\textwidth}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{D:/Blogfotos3/wpid-dsc5139.jpg}\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.24\textwidth}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{D:/Blogfotos3/wpid-dsc5251.jpg}\caption{\centering Ghostpipefish}\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

Here captions do work, but I'm struggling with the placement. I mean the H forces the pictures to be in the right spot, but there is plenty of unused whitespace and I don't want the book to have more than 500 pages ;-)

Any other suggestions or package that would fit my needs?

Thx in advance,
Flo

Comment: if longtable didn't allow more than one page it was probably used incorrectly but if you show no code we can't say what is wrong, but I suspect you don't need a table here.

Answer (score 2):

This will make a list of pages looking something like

[image]

I used `\captionof` so it numbers just those with a caption, you could easily adjust to number them all or none, depending on requirements.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{capt-of,graphicx}
\newcounter{pics}

\newcommand\z[2][]{%
  \ifnum\value{pics}=4\par\setcounter{pics}{1}\else\stepcounter{pics}\fi
  \ifhmode\unskip\hfill\fi
  \parbox[t]{.23\textwidth}{%
   \centering\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{#2}\par
   \ifx\relax#1\relax\else\captionof{figure}{#1}\fi}}
\errorcontextlines100
\begin{document}
\raggedright
\setlength\parskip{.5cm}
\z[zzz]{example-image}\z[hmmm]{example-image-a}\z{example-image-b}
\z{example-image}\z{example-image-a}\z[wwwwheeee]{example-image-b}
\z{example-image}\z{example-image-a}\z{example-image-b}
\z{example-image}\z[this...]{example-image-a}\z{example-image-b}
\z{example-image}\z{example-image-a}\z{example-image-b}
\z[a caption]{example-image}\z{example-image-a}\z{example-image-b}
\z{example-image}\z{example-image-a}\z{example-image-b}
\z{example-image}\z{example-image-a}\z{example-image-b}
\z{example-image}\z{example-image-a}\z{example-image-b}
\z{example-image}\z[caption]{example-image-a}\z{example-image-b}
\z{example-image}\z{example-image-b}\z{example-image-b}
\z{example-image}\z{example-image-b}\z{example-image-b}
\z{example-image}\z{example-image-a}\z{example-image-a}
\z{example-image}\z{example-image-a}\z{example-image-b}
\z{example-image}\z{example-image-a}\z{example-image-b}
\z{example-image}\z{example-image-a}\z{example-image-b}
\z{example-image}\z{example-image-a}\z{example-image-b}
\z{example-image}\z{example-image-a}\z{example-image-b}


\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response. very different approach that work's quite well with some slight modifications. The problem is: 
the size of a pic-sequence is completely random between 1 and let's say 50. In case there only 1 to 3 pics in a row of the grid, I would like to have them centered in the middle of the page and not justified but I can't figure out how to do that...

Comment: @Flo use `\centering` instead of `\raggedright` at the top.

Comment: I only want the picture-grid-parts of the document centered and not the text. And even with using \centering for the whole document the problem remains. e.g. as picture-block with 2 pics results in a row of 2 pictures, one being on the left edge of the page and the other one being on the right edge. I want them to be centered in the middle of the page, with a small space between them. I guess it might be due to the \hfill command. If I remove it there is no more space at all between the pictures.